# Right approach for asynchronous TcpListener using async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, threadpool, async-await, tcplistener

I have been thinking about what is the right way of set up a TCP server by using asynchronous programming.

Usually I would spawn a thread per incoming request, but I would like to do the most of the ThreadPool, so when connections are idle, there are no blocked threads.

First I would create the listener and start to accept clients, in this case, in a Console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8001);
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(endpoint); 

    server.Start();
    var task = AcceptTcpClients(server, cancellation.Token);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
    cancellation.Cancel();
    await task;
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

In that method, I would loop accepting incoming requests and spawning a new Task to handle the connection, so the loop can get back to accept more clients:

```
static async Task AcceptTcpClients(TcpListener server, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var ws = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (ws.IsConnected && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                String msg = await ws.ReadAsync();
                if (msg != null)
                    await ws.WriteAsync(ProcessResponse(msg));
            }
        }, token);
    }
 }
```

Creating new Task does not necessarily mean new thread, but is this the right way? Am I taking advantage of the ThreadPool or is there anything else I can do?

Is there any potential pitfall in this approach?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `await task;` in your `Main` won't compile; you'll have to use `task.Wait();` if you want to block on it.

Also, you should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` in asynchronous programming.

> Creating new Task does not necessarily mean new thread, but is this the right way?

You certainly *can* start up separate tasks (using `Task.Run`). Though you don't *have* to. You could just as easily call a separate `async` method to handle the individual socket connections.

There are a few problems with your actual socket handling, though. The `Connected` property is practically useless. You should always be continuously reading from a connected socket, even while you're writing to it. Also, you should be writing "keepalive" messages or have a timeout on your reads, so that you can detect half-open situations. I maintain a [TCP/IP .NET FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) that explains these common problems.

I really, strongly recommend that people do **not** write TCP/IP servers or clients. There are *tons* of pitfalls. It would be far better to self-host WebAPI and/or SignalR, if possible.

Comment: I was about to write an answer but this covers every single point, and more. Someone should write up the common pitfalls once and for all because you have given this answer way too often. You could piece together text snippets by now to answer all TCP questions.

Comment: Well, that is exactly the point, to learn about the pitfalls :). I am writing a WebSocketListener class, and I am trying to polish it now. I will take a look at your guide, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand though the "Task.Run" thing. Why is "Task.Factory.StartNew" not good?

Comment: @vtortola: It's not that `StartNew` is evil; it's just that `Run` is better. I explain it fully [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary The problem - I think - with webAPI or SignalR is that they're both fairly "vertical" solutions - e.g. SignalR seems to do TCP + persistent connections + push events to a javascript client. Is there a "TCP Server" layer that can be built on top of?

Comment: @RobertGrant: I think WebAPI would be the best approach; these days there's a general REST client for literally every platform, so WebAPI is easiest to consume. I'm not aware of a lower-level TCP server that doesn't also do HTTP, but I'm not completely familiar with ASP.NET Core internals.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks for the quick response on a 2014 answer :) Our task is to speak [MLLP](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=55), which is interesting!

Answer (score 5):

In order to stop a server accept loop gracefully, I register a callback that stops listening when the cancellationToken is cancelled (`cancellationToken.Register(listener.Stop);`).

This will throw a SocketException on `await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();` that is easy to capture.

There is no need for Task.Run(HandleClient()), because calling an async method returns a task that is running in parallel.

```
    public async Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(address, port);
        listener.Start();
        cancellationToken.Register(listener.Stop);
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                var clientTask = protocol.HandleClient(client, cancellationToken)
                    .ContinueWith(antecedent => client.Dispose())
                    .ContinueWith(antecedent => logger.LogInformation("Client disposed."));
            }
            catch (SocketException) when (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                logger.LogInformation("TcpListener stopped listening because cancellation was requested.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(new EventId(), ex, $"Error handling client: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what type of object is `protocol` in `protocol.HandleClient(client, cancellationToken)`

Comment: It's a class that handles the protocol specific communication over the TcpClient stream in `public async Task HandleClient(TcpClient client, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`.

Comment: Whith .Net 5.0 the thrown exception type has changed from ObjectDisposedException to SocketException. I've modified the code.